# Discrete spectrum for product of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive-definite self-ajoint operators on a Hilbert space $H$.
If the spectrum of both $A$ and $B$ is discrete, can we affirm that the spectrum of $AB$ will be also discrete ?
In finite dimension, it is true, but what happen in infinite dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little control on what the spectrum could be.

Consider first
$$
A_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},\qquad 
B_t=\begin{bmatrix} \cos t&\sin t\\ \sin t&-\cos t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos t&\sin t\\ \sin t&-\cos t\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $B_t$ is unitarily conjugate to $A$, the eigenvalues of $B_t$ are also $1$ and $2$. Both are positive definite.

Meanwhile, $A_0B_t$ [has eigenvalues](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%7D%7D.%7B%7Bcos%28t%29%2Csin%28t%29%7D%2C%7Bsin%28t%29%2C-cos%28t%29%7D%7D.%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%7D%7D.%7B%7Bcos%28t%29%2Csin%28t%29%7D%2C%7Bsin%28t%29%2C-cos%28t%29%7D%7D) 
$$\tag1
\lambda_{\pm}(t)=\frac14\,\Big(9+\cos2t\pm\sqrt{17+18\cos2t+\cos^22t\vphantom{\vspace{1cm}}}\Big).
$$
We have $$\lambda_+([0,\pi/2])=[2,4],\qquad \lambda_-([0,\pi/2])=[1,2].$$ Now let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,2\pi]$, and put
$$
A=\bigoplus_n A_0,\qquad B=\bigoplus_n B_{q_n}.
$$
Both $A$ and $B$ are positive, and both have spectrum $\{1,2\}$. Meanwhile, the spectrum of
$$
AB=\bigoplus_n A_0B_{q_n}
$$
has all the numbers $\lambda_+(q_n)$ and $\lambda_-(q_n)$, which are dense in $[1,4]$. As the spectrum is compact (and these operators are block diagonal),
$$
\sigma(AB)=[1,4].
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please give me what the big symbol "+" means in the expression of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: It's a direct sum. If you think of $A$ as a matrix, you have $$A=\begin{bmatrix} A_0\\ &A_0\\ &&\ddots\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Someone told me that considering A0 (the matrix)
and B as multiplication operators in $L^2(0, π)$ instead of an ad-hoc infinite sum space would be easier to explain. Can you please show me how ?

Comment: No idea what they mean, sorry.

Comment: I think if we see the operator $A$ as the infinite dimentional matrix associated with the following bounded integral operator $T_A:\mathbf L^2(0,\pi)\to \mathbf L^2(0,\pi)$, defined as follows:
For $f\in \mathbf L^2(0,\pi)$ with $f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_n(f)\,\mathrm{e}^{inx}$, $T_Uf=g$ with $g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat c_n\,\mathrm{e}^{inx}$ and $\hat c=(\hat c_n)^T_{n\in\mathbb Z}=U\cdot (c_n)^T_{n\in \mathbb Z}$. 
Similarly, $B$ is also viewed as a bounded operator $T_B$ on $\mathbf L^2(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine in what sense that would be easier. How would you calculate the spectrum, from that information?